# What should I update to resolve RCurl SSL version issue

Tags: r, libcurl, rcurl

When I run a sample code

```
require(RCurl)
search_example <- postForm(
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", 
  action  = "opensearch", 
  search  = "Te", 
  format  = "json"
)
```

I get an error

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    error:1407742E:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I understand that it's not an issue of RCurl itself but rather of SSL library it is using - but what exactly should I update?
Notably, standard methods from `utils` work without errors:

```
url_https <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Te"
download.file(url_https, tempfile(),  method = "libcurl")
download.file(url_https, tempfile(),  method = "curl")
```

I'm under Windows 10 (Pro, 64-bit), R version 3.6.1, RCurl package version 1.98-1.2.
`RCurl::curlVersion()$ssl_version` gives the following:

```
$age
[1] 3

$version
[1] "7.40.0"

$vesion_num
[1] 468992

$host
[1] "x86_64-pc-win32"

$features
      ssl      libz      ntlm asynchdns    spnego largefile       idn      sspi 
        4         8        16       128       256       512      1024      2048 

$ssl_version
[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.0o"

$ssl_version_num
[1] 0

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.8"

$protocols
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"  
[15] "scp"    "sftp"   "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"  

$ares
[1] ""

$ares_num
[1] 0

$libidn
[1] ""
```

Comment: Consider using the curl package instead of Rcurl

Comment: @HongOoi yes that's exactly what I've resorted to for now. But some of the old code uses RCurl and I'm not very eager to find and replace all those calls....

Comment: Any straightforward solution?

Comment: not that I found. Maybe we should report it to the developers...